# I Want to use gemfire in application with JPA+Spring+EclipseLink

Tags: spring, caching, jpa, eclipselink, gemfire

I am working on a project related with Auction. 
Spring+JPA+EclipseLink 
I have to use Gemfire as cache. So I want to know whether it is possible or not? And if possible which configuration I need to add? i.e. JAR FILES to be add, ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES to be set,property to be add in PERSISTENT.xml etc. If you have any working example, it will be a great help.

Thanks in Advance,
 Tushar Dodia

Answer (score 0):

Gemfire should be able to cache any Java object, so it should be possible. You should walk through the Gemfire [documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabricNoSuite/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.gemfire.7.0/about_users_guide.html) itself, and then check out the [Spring Data Gemfire project](http://www.springsource.org/spring-gemfire). David Turanksi, the project lead, has plenty of examples on github.